# Selective retrieval of data from Firebase to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

In my Android application, I am using `RecyclerView` with `CardView`. The contents of the `RecyclerView` are fetched from Firebase Realtime Database. For that I have used `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` from FirebaseUI. The entries in the database correspond to POJO of class Bus.

```
public class Bus {
    private String source;
    private String destination;
    private long available;
    private String date;
    private long fare;

    Bus() {

    }

    Bus(String source,String destination,long available,String date,long fare) {
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.available = available;
        this.date = date;
        this.fare = fare;
    }

    public long getAvailable() {
        return available;
    }

    public long getFare() {
        return fare;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setAvailable(long available) {
        this.available = available;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public void setFare(long fare) {
        this.fare = fare;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

}
```

In an activity, I accept the source, destination and date from the user. My intention is to display only the relevant data in the `RecyclerView`. This is my `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` code:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Bus,BusViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new     FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Bus,BusViewHolder>(Bus.class,R.layout.bus_card,BusViewHolder.class,mDatabase) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BusViewHolder viewHolder,Bus model,int position) {
            if(model.getSource().equals(source) && model.getDestination().equals(destination) && model.getDate().equals(date)) // This is the criteria for displaying the card
            {
                viewHolder.setSource(model.getSource());
                viewHolder.setDestination(model.getDestination());
                viewHolder.setAvailable(model.getAvailable());
                viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
                viewHolder.setFare(model.getFare());
            }
        }

    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

Here is my `ViewHolder`:

```
public static class BusViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public BusViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        TextView src = mView.findViewById(R.id.source);
        src.setText("Source " + source);
    }

    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        TextView dest = mView.findViewById(R.id.destination);
        dest.setText("Destination " + destination);
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        TextView dte = mView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        dte.setText("Date " + date);
    }

    public void setAvailable(long available) {
        TextView avail = mView.findViewById(R.id.available);
        avail.setText("Available Seats " + Long.toString(available));
    }

    public void setFare(long fare) {
        TextView fre = mView.findViewById(R.id.fare);
        fre.setText("Fare " + Long.toString(fare));
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it displays the relevant cards, however there are empty cards for data which does not satisfy the condition. Is it possible to selectively retrieve data into the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`? Currently, the total number of cards created in the `RecyclerView` is equal to the total entries in the database.

Comment: You pass a Query object into FirebaseRecyclerAdapter that describes the results you wish to show.  If you can't build a query that contains only the items to show, then you can't use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

Comment: Thank you. I was apprehensive about query as firebase doesn't support multiple `orderby` clauses. But now I've added an extra child in my node as a workaround

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Will be helpful for you if I'll provide you a detailed answer? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes I solved the problem by passing a query object to the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and modifying my database nodes. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @EdmundFitzgerald Good to hear that, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `query` object to retrieve selectively from the `Realtime Database`. As `query` doesn't support multiple `orderby` clauses, I had to add an additional field in my node. This is the updated `firebaserecycleradapter`

```
query = mDatabase.orderByChild("sourcedestinationdate").equalTo(source+destination+date);
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Bus,BusViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Bus,BusViewHolder>(Bus.class,R.layout.bus_card,BusViewHolder.class,query) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BusViewHolder viewHolder,Bus model,int position) {
            viewHolder.setSource(model.getSource());
            viewHolder.setDestination(model.getDestination());
            viewHolder.setAvailable(model.getAvailable());
            viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
            viewHolder.setFare(model.getFare());
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

Note that the last parameter in `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is `query`.